# Facebook like button OG-tags

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a method like this:

```
private void LoadMetaTagsForFacebook()
{
    HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.Attributes.Add("property", "fb:app_id");
    meta.Attributes.Add("content", "");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);

    meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.Attributes.Add("property", "og:url");
    meta.Attributes.Add("content", Request.Url.ToString());
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);

    meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.Attributes.Add("property", "og:site_name");
    meta.Attributes.Add("content", "Site.com");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);

    meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.Attributes.Add("property", "og:title");
    meta.Attributes.Add("content", this._product.Name);
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);

    meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.Attributes.Add("property", "og:image");
    meta.Attributes.Add("content", this._product.ImagePath);
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);

    meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.Attributes.Add("property", "og:type");
    meta.Attributes.Add("content", "drink");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
}
```

But when i run the debugger i get this error:

Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

1. When i look at the page source on the site the meta tags is right.. do i have to add the meta tags in a other way? How do i do that?
2. I also get a error because i have a redirect path (you have to be logged in to see the page). What´s the solution for this?

I would be very happy for an answear and i accept the answears if the help me.. i have spent 3 hours searching and trying.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score -1):

Try using "Name" instead of "Property", I made a test here and it works.

```
        meta= new HtmlMeta();
        meta.Attributes.Add("name", "og:title");
        meta.Content = this._product.Name;
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

Comment: Can that work with HTML tags too? `<meta name='[...]'>`